# zend forms submit button

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am writing a code in zend to capture data from a users input and and save it in the database. I am using zend forms. The information to capture is too much, so I created another form to fill in the other data...The first form works well, but when I press next to submit the first form to the database, to also redirect to the second form i get this error:
 Fatal error: Call to a member function setLabel() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gforms2\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 114

When I comment that line the the second form, the user can only "view and input info", the submit button is not visible..please help

Here is my code for Forms, Indexcontroller and models

```
IndexController

<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
        $this->view->organization_details= $organization_details->fetchAll();
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_OrganizationDetails();

        $form->submit->setLabel('Next');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                $Organization_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Name');
                $Organization_Trading_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Trading_Name');
                $Region = $form->getValue('Region');
                $City = $form->getValue('City');
                $Physical_Address = $form->getValue('Physical_Address');
                $Physical_code = $form->getValue('Physical_code');
                $Postal_Address = $form->getValue('Postal_Address');
                $Postal_code = $form->getValue('Postal_code');
                $Telephone_Number = $form->getValue('Telephone_Number');
                $Fax_Number = $form->getValue('Fax_Number');
                $Cellular_Number = $form->getValue('Cellular_Number');
                $Organization_Email = $form->getValue('Organization_Email');
                $Organization_Website = $form->getValue('Organization_Website');                                

                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->addOrganizationDetails($Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website);

                $this->_helper->redirector('addform2');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }

    }
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_OrganizationDetails();
        $form->submit->setLabel('save'); //can set it here also in forms
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $id = (int)$form->getValue('id');
                $Organization_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Name');
                $Organization_Trading_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Trading_Name');
                $Region = $form->getValue('Region');
                $City = $form->getValue('City');
                $Physical_Address = $form->getValue('Physical_Address');
                $Physical_code = $form->getValue('Physical_code');
                $Postal_Address = $form->getValue('Postal_Address');
                $Postal_code = $form->getValue('Postal_code');
                $Telephone_Number = $form->getValue('Telephone_Number');
                $Fax_Number = $form->getValue('Fax_Number');
                $Cellular_Number = $form->getValue('Cellular_Number');
                $Organization_Email = $form->getValue('Organization_Email');
                $Organization_Website = $form->getValue('Organization_Website');
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->updateOrganizationDetails($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        } else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            if ($id > 0) {
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $form->populate($organization_details->getOrganizationDetails($id));
            }

    }
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
            if ($del == 'Yes') {
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->deleteOrganizationDetails($id);
            }
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
            $this->view->organization_details = $organization_details->getOrganizationDetails($id);
        }
    }

   public function addform2Action()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_PersonalDetails();

        $form->submit2->setLabel('Next');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                $First_Name = $form->getValue('First_Name');
                $Last_Name = $form->getValue('Last_Name');
                $Telephone_Number = $form->getValue('Telephone_Number');
                $Fax_Number = $form->getValue('Fax_Number');
                $Cellular_Number = $form->getValue('Cellular_Number');
                $Email_Address = $form->getValue('Email_Address');
                $Username= $form->getValue('Username');
                $Password = $form->getValue('Password');
                $Confirm_Password = $form->getValue('Confirm_Password');                            

                $personaldetails= new Application_Model_DbTable_PersonalDetails();
                $personaldetails->addform2PersonalDetails($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Email_Address, $Username, $Password, $Confirm_Password);


                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }

    }
    }




}


form1

<?php
class Application_Form_OrganizationDetails extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('organization_details');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $Organization_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Name');
        $Organization_Name->setLabel('Organization Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Organization_Trading_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Trading_Name');
        $Organization_Trading_Name->setLabel('Organization Trading Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Region= new Zend_Form_Element_Select('Region');
        $Region->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width: 150px;'));  
        $Region ->setLabel('Region')
                ->addMultiOptions(array(
                            '--Select One--'=>'--Select One--',
                            'City of Johannesburg'=>'City of Johannesburg',
                            'City of Tswane'=>'City of Tswane',
                            'Ekhurhuleni Metropolitian Municipality'=>'Ekhurhuleni Metropolitian Municipality',
                            'West Rand District Municipality'=>'West Rand District Municipality',
                            'Sedibeng District Municipality '=>'Sedibeng District Municipality',

                        ));


        $City = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('City');
        $City->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width: 144px;'));  
        $City ->setLabel('City')
            ->addMultiOptions(array(
                            'Pretoria'=>'Pretoria',
                            'Gauteng'=>'Gauteng',
                            'Katlego'=>'Katlego',

                        )); 


        $Physical_Address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Physical_Address');
        $Physical_Address->setLabel('Physical Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Physical_code = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Physical_code');
        $Physical_code->setLabel('Physical code')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Postal_Address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Postal_Address');
        $Postal_Address->setLabel('Postal Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Postal_code = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Postal_code');
        $Postal_code->setLabel('Postal code')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Telephone_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Telephone_Number');
        $Telephone_Number->setLabel('Telephone Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Fax_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Fax_Number');
        $Fax_Number->setLabel('Fax Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Cellular_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Cellular_Number');
        $Cellular_Number->setLabel('Cellular Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Organization_Email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Email');
        $Organization_Email->setLabel('Organization Email')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('EmailAddress');

        $Organization_Website = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Website');
        $Organization_Website->setLabel('Organization Website')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');




        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website, $submit));
    }
}

form2
<?php

class Application_Form_PersonalDetails extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('personaldetails');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $First_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('First_Name');
        $First_Name->setLabel('First Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Last_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Last_Name');
        $Last_Name->setLabel('Last Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Telephone_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Telephone_Number');
        $Telephone_Number->setLabel('Telephone Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Fax_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Fax_Number');
        $Fax_Number->setLabel('Fax Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Cellular_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Cellular_Number');
        $Cellular_Number->setLabel('Cellular Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Email_Address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Email_Address');
        $Email_Address->setLabel('Email Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('EmailAddress');

        $Username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Username');
        $Username->setLabel('Username')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');


        $Password= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Password');
        $Password->setLabel('Password')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Confirm_Password= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Confirm_Password');
        $Confirm_Password->setLabel('Confirm Password')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');





        $submit2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit2->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $First_Name, $Last_Name, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Email_Address, $Username, $Password, $Confirm_Password));
    }


}

model for form1 
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'organization_details';

    public function getOrganizationDetails($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

    public function addOrganizationDetails($Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Organization_Name'=> $Organization_Name,
            'Organization_Trading_Name'=> $Organization_Trading_Name,
            'Region'=> $Region,
            'City'=> $City,
            'Physical_Address'=> $Physical_Address,
            'Physical_code'=> $Physical_code,
            'Postal_Address'=> $Postal_Address,
            'Postal_code'=> $Postal_code,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Organization_Email'=> $Organization_Email,
            'Organization_Website'=> $Organization_Website,
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }

    public function updateOrganizationDetails($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Organization_Name'=> $Organization_Name,
            'Organization_Trading_Name'=> $Organization_Trading_Name,
            'Region'=> $Region,
            'City'=> $City,
            'Physical_Address'=> $Physical_Address,
            'Physical_code'=> $Physical_code,
            'Postal_Address'=> $Postal_Address,
            'Postal_code'=> $Postal_code,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Organization_Email'=> $Organization_Email,
            'Organization_Website'=> $Organization_Website,
        );
        $this->update($data, 'id = '. (int)$id);
    }

    public function deleteOrganizationDetails($id)
    {
        $this->delete('id =' . (int)$id);
    }


}

model for form2

<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_PersonalDetails extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'personaldetails';

        public function getPersonalDetails($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

    public function addform2PersonalDetails($First_Name, $Last_Name, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Email_Address, $Username,$Password, $Confirm_Password)
    {
        $data = array(
            'First_Name'=> $First_Name,
            'Last_Name'=> $Last_Name,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Email_Address'=> $Email_Address,
            'Username'=> $Username,
            'Password'=> $Password,
            'Confirm_Password'=> $Confirm_Password,
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }

    public function PersonalDetails($id, $First_Name, $Last_Name, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Email_Address, $Username,$Password, $Confirm_Password)
    {
        $data = array(
            'First_Name'=> $First_Name,
            'Last_Name'=> $Last_Name,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Email_Address'=> $Email_Address,
            'Username'=> $Username,
            'Password'=> $Password,
            'Confirm_Password'=> $Confirm_Password,
        );
        $this->update($data, 'id = '. (int)$id);
    }

    public function PersonalDetails($id)
    {
        $this->delete('id =' . (int)$id);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why you just don't set the label of the submit button in the form?

Comment: I tried it the is no error this time, but still my next button does not appear.

Comment: Thanks for the help i figured that i needed to add my $submit in my add elements  $this->addElements(array($id, $First_Name, $Last_Name, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Email_Address, $Username, $Password, $Confirm_Password, $submit));